# CSS element keeps going to new line

Tags: html, css

I want to keep the text block always on the first line, and if it needs multiple lines, then those lines should always get created beneath the first line of text.

The objective is that you only see dates on the left part of the page.

what is happening:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKVfE.png)

what should be happening:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jBdR.png)

```css
/* Magic */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
    margin-left:20px;
}

/* MAIN STRUCTURE */
.page {
    margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
}

.section {
    margin-top: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Header */
#title {
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}

#meta {
    float: right;
}

/* section */
.timeline_entry {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.entry {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

#identity {

}

#current {

}

#actions {

}

#stats {

}

#listing {

}

/* entry */
.element {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0.8rem;
}

.word {
    display: inline-block;
}

#editing{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    float: right;
}

#proposal_status {

}

#proposal_text {

}

/* header */
#user_actions{

}
```

```html
    <div class="section" id="listing">
        <div class="timeline_entry">
            <div class="entry">
                <div class="element">
                    <div class="word">2015-09-23</div>
                    <div class="word"><a href="">#</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="element">This is a long text which is going to the second line because its so big you know? more text, moarr</div>
            </div>
            <div class="entry">
                <div class="element">
                    <div class="word">2015-09-23</div>
                    <div class="word"><a href="">#</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="element">Achieved</div>
                <div class="element"><a href="">Talk (5)</a></div>
                <div class="element">
                    <div class="word"><a href="">Category</a></div>
                    <div class="word"><a href="">Category</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline_entry">
            <div class="entry">
                <div class="element">
                    <div class="word">2015-09-23</div>
                    <div class="word"><a href="">#</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="element">This text stays where it should</div>
            </div>
            <div class="entry">
                <div class="element">
                    <div class="word">2015-09-23</div>
                    <div class="word"><a href="">#</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="element">Achieved</div>
                <div class="element"><a href="">Talk (5)</a></div>
                <div class="element">
                    <div class="word"><a href="">Category</a></div>
                    <div class="word"><a href="">Category</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: It would be easier (and possibly more semantically correct) to use a table for this.

Comment: Can you add in image to show what it is doing and what it needs to be doing

Comment: @Shi-ii i edited the question and added two images of what is happening and what should be happening.. tks

Comment: You could use a table or the CSS flexbox, which is now well supported by the browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try playing around with HTMLs much underloved ["Deffinition List"](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dl.asp) `<dl>`

Alternatively, here's a table-like layout:

```css
.list-group {
 display:table;
 width:100%;
 max-width:500px;
}
.item {
 display:table-row;
}
.date {
 display:table-cell;
 width:30%;
 padding:10px;
 vertical-align:top;
 text-align:right;
}
.dates {
 display:table-cell;
 width:70%;
 padding:10px;
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-group">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="date">2015 09 14</div>
    <div class="dates"><a href="#">2013123</a> <a href="#">2013123</a> <a href="#">2013123</a> <a href="#">2013123</a> <a href="#">2013123</a> <a href="#">2013123</a> <a href="#">2013123</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="date">2015 09 14</div>
    <div class="dates"><a href="#">2013123</a> <a href="#">2013123</a> <a href="#">2013123</a> <a href="#">2013123</a> <a href="#">2013123</a> <a href="#">2013123</a> <a href="#">2013123</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="date">2015 09 14</div>
    <div class="dates"><a href="#">2013123</a> <a href="#">2013123</a> <a href="#">2013123</a> <a href="#">2013123</a> <a href="#">2013123</a> <a href="#">2013123</a> <a href="#">2013123</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="date">2015 09 14</div>
    <div class="dates"><a href="#">2013123</a> <a href="#">2013123</a> <a href="#">2013123</a> <a href="#">2013123</a> <a href="#">2013123</a> <a href="#">2013123</a> <a href="#">2013123</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping to comment but I don't have enough rep points to do so, but would the below work?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4r295p0q/2/

This won't work if your class assignments aren't flexible because I changed the classes of the two `DIV`'s with the text from `.element` (red border) to `.post` (blue border). From there, I gave the new `.post` class an pre-determined `width` percentage and `float: right`.